# How can I store objects in a session in PHP?

Tags: php, persistence, pdo

Hello I would like to store or save an object inside a session, using classes like `SessionHandler` or arrays $_SESSION,I've seen that it is possible if I serialize the object, and I don't want to lose the methods of that object instance.
I've seen serializing is possible but the object I want to store is created by PDOStatement::fetchObject() although the instance class is `Users` I get this error:

> PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances
> Why? It is not a PDO instance..

Sorry I am Spanish and I don't speak English very well..
Thanks

Comment: Show how are you trying to serialize it, from the exception it seems that you are trying to serialize statement, not it's result.

Comment: What @dev-null-dweller said.  I can serialize the result of `PDOStatement::fetchObject` just fine.

Comment: If the object is from the database, why would you want to serialize it in a session? Just grab it from the DB again. Sessions should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP's native `$_SESSION` sessions transparently serialize and unserialize objects that support PHP's [serialization protocol](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php) or the [`Serializable` interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php). You do not need to explicitly serialize them.

PHP cannot serialize [`resources`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) because these are handles to some stateful resource outside PHP's control. This is why you cannot serialize `PDO` or `PDOStatement` objects.

By default an object is serialized by saving all property names and values and unserialized by creating an object with the same class (without invoking the constructor) and directly setting the serialized properties. You can customize serialization behavior for your objects using the `__sleep` and `__wakeup` magic methods or by implementing the `Serializable` interface. But not both! If you use `implements Serializable`, `__sleep` and `__wakeup` are ignored.

*One important note:* when using object serialization, you *must* have the class definition loaded before you unserialize (or have an autoloader that can load it) and it *must* match the class definition of the object that was serialized. Class definitions are not stored in the serialized data.

For example suppose you have the following:

```
class Test {
    public $version = 1;
    protected $abc;
    public function setAbc($abc) {
        $this->abc = $abc;
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->setAbc(123);
$_SESSION['mytest'] = $t;
```

Now imagine you change `Test` one day to be like this instead:

```
class Test {
    public $version = 2;
    private $def;
    public function setDef ($def) {
        $this->def = $def;
    }
}
```

Now suppose you load into your new code an object serialized when `Test` was at version 1:

```
$t = $_SESSION['mytest']; // this was stored yesterday, when Test was version 1

var_dump($t)
```

You will get this:

```
object(Test)#1 (3) {
  ["version"]=>
  int(1)
  ["def":"Test":private]=>
  NULL
  ["abc":protected]=>
  int(123)
}
```

Furthermore, you can't use old methods:

```
if ($t->version == 1) { // Check for class version
    $t->setAbc(345); // "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Test::setAbc()"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem,but I have a new problem,on that class I pass the PDO Object in __constructor(that is connected to MySQL) and I set a member variable to PDO Object, but when I unserialize the "container object" it doesn't execute __constructor function,so the member variable that is a PDO object will not be set..
How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: This is explained in the answer. Constructors are not executed because the object is *restored* not *initialized*. Create a `__wakeup()` or the `Serializer` interface `unserialize()` method that does what you want, or add a `setPDO()` method and set the PDO object manually. Bottom line, though, **you should not serialize objects that contain resources**! Use a different class design.

Comment: Thank you so much,I like your idea adding a setPDO method,you are right :)